# Python PyQt WebView Load Multiple Local Web Pages

Tags: python, pyqt, python-multithreading

I am currently building an application that uses the Twitter API to return posts based on a keyword search. The application retrieves posts every minute and updates multiple webviews that contain different information. I have 4 different web views:

1. Display All Posts retrieved
2. Display Charts
3. Display Tag Cloud
4. Display Other statistical Information

I am using threading to retrieve data from the API. The application runs well up until the point when I need to load the local html files that have been updated to include the new html that shows the information. When it loads all 4 pages it freezes the application for about 20 seconds.

This code calls the 'updateWebViews' function once the workerThread has done its job:

```
self.workerThread = updateThread()
        self.connect(self.workerThread, QtCore.SIGNAL('EMIT'), self.updateWebViews())
```

The below code updates all 4 pages and freezes the application:

```
def updateWebViews(self):

            print('Updating Web Views')

            self.postRetrievedText.load(
                (QtCore.QUrl("posts.html")))

            self.tagCloudWebView.load(
                (QtCore.QUrl("tagCloud.html")))

            self.barChartWebView.load(
                (QtCore.QUrl("index.html")))

            self.webView.load(
                (QtCore.QUrl("statistics.html")))

            print('Finished Updating Web Views')
```

I've checked the other posts on the forum but they don't quite solve my problem. I need to load each page without crashing the GUI.

Thanks!

Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

So 1 by 1 I commented out the calls to load each webpage. 'tagcloud.html', 'statistics.html' and 'index.html' loaded instantly. The problem was with 'posts.html'.

'posts.html' contained a call to googles fonts and changed the font of the text on the webpage. I took the google font out and no more crashing!